# Hibernate re-creates entity previously deleted upon merge() - how to avoid?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I delete an entity in one transaction and later merge the entity again in another transaction, Hibernate will create the entity with a new ID in the database.

I expected it to throw an IllegalArgumentException as per [EntityManager's JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-).

The environment: Hibernate 5.2.x with Spring Data 2.0.x

**Questions:**

- How can I get the EntityManager to throw an exception?
- What is the best workaround if that is not possible? For now I check the ID of the entity after save() completed: If it changed, the entity has been re-created.

Code to reproduce the problem - here the two threads are replaced by a flush/clear that leads to the same situation:

```
// given...
MyEntity entity = jpaRepository.findByXXX("0001");
jpaRepository.delete(entity);
em.flush();
em.clear();

// when...
Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> jpaRepository.save(entity));

// then...
// FAILs as no exception was thrown, instead entity with new ID was returned
assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class);
```

The problems seems to be rooted inside [DefaultMergeEventListener](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultMergeEventListener.java) where it generates a new ID if it doesn't find the entity in the database.

```
                final PersistenceContext persistenceContext = source.getPersistenceContextInternal();
                EntityEntry entry = persistenceContext.getEntry( entity );
                if ( entry == null ) {
                    EntityPersister persister = source.getEntityPersister( event.getEntityName(), entity );
                    Serializable id = persister.getIdentifier( entity, source );
                    if ( id != null ) {
                        final EntityKey key = source.generateEntityKey( id, persister );
                        final Object managedEntity = persistenceContext.getEntity( key );
                        entry = persistenceContext.getEntry( managedEntity );
                        if ( entry != null ) {
                            // we have specialized case of a detached entity from the
                            // perspective of the merge operation.  Specifically, we
                            // have an incoming entity instance which has a corresponding
                            // entry in the current persistence context, but registered
                            // under a different entity instance
                            entityState = EntityState.DETACHED;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You are calling em.clear(); and that clears the PersistenceContext how should Hibernate know that you removed the entity? Plus what's the ID generation strategy?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Hibernates goes to the database with `persistenceContext.getEntry( entity )` and knows that the entity doesn't exist.

Comment: Which ID generation strategy do you use?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I'm using the standard hibernate sequence generator `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`

Comment: Ok. And do you get a new sequence or is it saved with the old sequence?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Spring JPA looks at the entity and sees that the ID is already set in the POJO, then calls merge(). Then Hibernate behaves like it doesn't care somec called merge(), instead it behaves like save()

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I get a new sequence number, it is not saved with the old sequence number. The new sequence number is also returned to me as the caller.

Comment: If you remove flush() and clear() the test passes. I doubt that Hibernate would execute a query to find out that you have deleted the record on the database. This will not make sense because every delete will need a select before. So IMHO the behavior is correct.

Comment: Btw. "if instance is not an entity or is a removed entity" from the JavaDoc is only valid as long as you are in the same PersistenceContext. And this is destroyed by flush and clear

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - so how to I handle a situation when an entity is removed in one persistence context by a user, and an old instance is saved by another user in another persistence context? If it would have been an update, I would have received an OptimisticLockException. This way I end up with a resurrected entity in the database with a new ID.  Is comparing the ID before and after merge() the only way to proceed?

Comment: You should ask the question: How would you do it without Hibernate? When you delete the row in the table there is no way to find out if it already existed or not. In that case you should consider a soft delete strategy.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - in a non-hibernate environment I would have issued an update on the row, as the entity already has an ID. I would put the version number of the entity in the where clause for optimistic locking. If the update would have returned zero updated rows, the row would have been deleted, or modified by someone else. This would trigger an error message to the user saying that the entity they try to update has been modified by someone else.

Comment: I understand. The only solution that I see is to call Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class); and then  session.update(a); This will result in a OptimisticLockException